# AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

Not sure why each time I build my project and re-run my Razor Pages, I will get this error.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (IDW10502: An
> MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user.
> See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. )
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An
> MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user.
> See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable
> scopes, string authenticationScheme, string tenantId, string userFlow,
> ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)

My temporary workaround is to clear browsing data (cache, cookies). After that, I need to relogin.

This is my program.cs (.NET 6).

```
var graphScope = builder.Configuration["GraphSettings:Scope"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(graphScope)
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

I also get another error

```
MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string authenticationScheme, string tenantId, string userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
```

But, when I check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, the value is `true`.

The error happened in these lines.

```
var graphScope = _configuration["GraphSettings:Scope"];
AccessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { graphScope });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround with custom IDistributedCache**

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(graphScope)
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The last line (**AddInMemoryTokenCaches**) configure application to use in-memory cache that is empty after each server restart. We need to find a way to store tokens outside the app process and restore the cache after process restart.

[image]

The only alternative to **AddInMemoryTokenCaches** is **AddDistributedTokenCaches** with ability to store tokens in memory